# Check for the homoscedacity with plot (car package)

Tags: r, regression

I am running the model on the Sales and Prices. I have actual and regular price and made a price index from it (ACT\REG).
The code is:

```
simple.fit<-lm(log(mydata.FASales)~log(PriceIndiceFA), data=ModelData) 
summary(simple.fit) 
simple.fit<-lm(log(mydata.FASales)~log(PriceIndiceFA), data=ModelData) 
summary(simple.fit) 
# Linearity Plots 
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
plot(simple.fit)
```

When I see the graphs for the OLS assumption, I find them weird:

[image: Plot1]

[image: Plot2]

Could you please tell what it means? Do I have a homoscedacity in the errors? Or did I transform my data wrong?

Comment: Since this is about interpretation of statistics, not the code itself, I'm voting to move this to [stats.se]. You might check there for similar questions

Comment: Why do you fit a log-log model?